# How to modify MTU?

Tags: networking, 18.04, ssh, internet, systemd

To change MTU, I tried `ifconfig wifi0 mtu 1200`, but the mtu is still 1500 as before.

```
$ ifconfig
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 1500
...    
wifi0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
...
$ sudo ifconfig wifi0 mtu 1200
$ ifconfig
<same output as before>
```

I also tried to add `mtu 1200` to `/etc/network/interfaces` or `/etc/ppp/options`. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I am playing around with such a problem here as well and found out, that you can find a lot of connection settings with

```
nmcli connection show <ConnectionName>
```

When you found the setting in question you can modify it with

```
nmcli connection modify <ConnectionName> (+-)?<setting>.<prob> Value
```

Unfortunately I do not have a use-case to test this with a wifi network as I try to fix stuff for a VPN and vpn-plugins for network-manager receive this setting via individual interfaces.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Just to mention that using the NetworkManager I could change the MTU with the commands:  

`nmcli connection show <ConnectionName>`   
`nmcli connection modify "<ConnectionName>" 802-11-wireless.mtu 1492`


Then reconnect again.

Answer (score 0):

NetworManager have its config files in

```
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections
```

so you can edit mtu there and restart

```
# systemctl restart NetworkManager
```